# how to find no of records and no of duplicates in a table using single query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

hey guys i want to know is that possible to write a query to find no of records and no of duplicate records using single query
 here i know to get no of record below is the query

```
 select count(*) from table
```

and the query to find no of duplicates is

```
select count(country) from table group by country having count(country)>1
```

here country is one column name in table.but i need one single query which display total no of records in table as well  as duplicate records on country column ..when i try to write like this

```
select count(*),count(country) from table group by country having count(country)>1
```

but i didn't work out
i think this is the worst query which i wrote but plz forgive me ..can some one help me to sole this ?

thank you

Comment: Please can you give sample tables and expected result ?

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're trying to achieve here. Sample data and expected results would would mice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `subquery` :

```
SELECT COUNT(country) AS duplicate_country, 
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table t1) AS Total_count
FROM table t
GROUP BY country
HAVING COUNT(country) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want  the number of country with duplicate  you could use

```
    select country, count(*) 
    from table 
    group by country 
    having count(country)>1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
SELECT COUNT(*)  as total_counts, 
      (SELECT COUNT(country) FROM table tablename A GROUP BY country
              HAVING COUNT(country) > 1) as duplicates
from tablename;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want numbers, then I think you want:

```
select count(*) as num_records,
       count(*) - count(distinct country) as num_duplicates
from t;
```